# How to get individual curve point positions in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created a curve by using the Curve line node in Geometry Nodes.

Now I would like to get the point positions of curve points.
Actually I need the vector position of the first point of the curve and the last one.

The curve shape is changing and I would like to know the dynamic vertex positions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answers by Eric. You can found him at Mastodon: https://mstdn.social/@3d_eric@mas.to

"*Sadly you can´t simply use the 'attribute statistic' node to get the start and end location. The vector that you get will be the minimum and maximum coordinates in world space. I have a bent curve in my example. As you can see, the objects are placed in the global lower left and upper right corner of the curve object, but not at the endpoints.*"
[image]

**The best way:**

"*You can use a 'sample curve' node to pick the location, normal and tangent of a specific curve point. To sample the start of a curve you choose the 'curve factor' of 0. For the end you set it to 1. The curve factor is a value from 0 to 1 that runs along the whole curve.
I often instance stuff, thats why i like to use the 'Endpoint Selection' method. Its the second screenshot. The integer value in the selection defines how many points you select from each side of the curve.*"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself and prepared you a shot, how to do it by using the *Sample Index* node.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way to get global point positions in objects, like curves or mesh lines:

[image]